# Trouble creating Xtext grammar with semantic newlines

Tags: eclipse, antlr, xtext

I am just getting started with Xtext, and I'm having a bit of trouble using newlines semantically (the newlines affect how the lexer assigns fragments).

Here is a very simple test case:

```
Feature: The quick brown fox 
    Jumps over
    The lazy dog
```

When parsing this text using this grammar...

```
grammar com.example.model.Model hidden(WS)

import "http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" as ecore
generate model "http://www.example.com/model"


Feature:
    'Feature' ':' title=Title NL+
        narrative=Narrative?;

Title:
    (WORD) (WORD)*;

Narrative:
    ((WORD) (WORD)* NL+)+;


terminal WORD: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')*;

// WS should not include newlines because it is semantic
terminal WS: (' ' | '\t');

terminal NL: ('\r'? '\n');
```

I would expect title to contain "The quick brown fox" and narrative to contain "Jumps over\nThe lazy dog"

But instead I get a `org.eclipse.xtext.diagnostics.Diagnostic.Syntax` error of `extraneous input '\n' expecting 'Feature'`.

However, if I remove the narrative from the example text I get no parse errors with title assigned correctly.

I have looked through a lot of examples, but these tend to be for very large and complex languages, or have very clear start/end tags to match.

Could anyone please help explain where my expectations are failing in this very simple case?

**Update**

So apparently my expectations were correct, it's my test case that is failing.

```
@RunWith(XtextRunner)
@InjectWith(CucumberInjectorProvider)
class ValidationTest {

    static void assertThatValidation(List<Issue> issues, Matcher matches) {
        assertThat(issues, matches)
    }

    static Matcher hasNoIssues() {
        return emptyCollectionOf(Issue)
    }

    static Matcher theError(String expectedCode) {
        return allOf(hasProperty("code", equalTo(expectedCode)),
                hasProperty("severity", equalTo(Severity.ERROR)))
    }

    static Matcher theWarning(String expectedCode) {
        return allOf(hasProperty("code", equalTo(expectedCode)),
                hasProperty("severity", equalTo(Severity.WARNING)))
    }

    @Inject
    ParseHelper<Feature> parserHelper

    @Inject
    ValidationTestHelper validationTestHelper

    List<Issue> whenParsing(String content) {
        Feature model = parserHelper.parse(content.stripIndent())
        assertThat(model, not(null))
        return validationTestHelper.validate(model)
    }

    @Test
    void featureWithSimpleTitle() {
        assertThatValidation whenParsing("Feature: Hello World\n"),
                hasNoIssues()
    }

    @Test
    void featureWithSimpleTitleAndNarrative() {
        def input = '''
            Feature: The quick brown fox 
                Jumps over
                The lazy dog
        '''
        assertThatValidation whenParsing(input), hasNoIssues()
    }
}
```

But this seems ok...

```
@RunWith(XtextRunner)
@InjectWith(CucumberInjectorProvider)
class CucumberParsingTest {
    @Inject
    ParseHelper<Feature> parseHelper

    @Test
    def void loadModel() {
        val result = parseHelper.parse('''
            Feature: The quick brown fox 
                Jumps over
                The lazy dog
        ''')
        Assert.assertNotNull(result)
        val errors = result.eResource.errors
        Assert.assertTrue('''Unexpected errors: «errors.join(", ")»''', errors.isEmpty)
    }
}
```

Sorry my questions ended up being so off topic.

Comment: cannot reproduce this with the grammar and example you gave
=> can you please provide a failing unit test too.

Comment: Oh no, a red herring! Apparently it doesn't like my Groovy tests. Any idea what the XTest test is doing differently so that I can make sure my strings get passed in correctly to the parserHelper?

Comment: i have no idea sry

Comment: maybe the groovy model starts with a `\n`

Comment: Yeah, there were some strange differences in how groovy handles newlines. I ended up just ditching Groovy and learning XTend. This thread should be closed in shame. :/